# Why am I able to link without including ctype.h

Tags: c, gcc, gcc4.9

- Without `#include<ctype.h>`, the following program outputs 1 and 0.
- With the include, it outputs 1 and 1.

I am using TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit. I wonder what the implementation of `isdigit` is in the first case, and **why it is able to link**.

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d %d\n",isdigit(48),isdigit(48.4));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could it be that ctype.h redefines isdigit as a macro?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit nope, I'm not hiding anything. Moreover, if you just copied the program and pasted into ideone it seems to compile and link just fine on GCC 5.1, but it crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default GCC uses the C90 standard (with GNU extensions ([reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Standards.html#Standards))) which allows implicit declarations. The problem with your case is that you have two calls to `isdigit` with two different arguments which might confuse the compiler when it creates the implicit declaration of the function, and it probably selects `int isdigit(double)` to be on the safe side. That is of course the wrong prototype for the function, which means that when the library function is called at run-time it will be called with wrong arguments and you will have *undefined behavior*.

When you include the `<ctype.h>` header file, there is a correct prototype, and then the compiler know that [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) takes an `int` argument and can convert the `double` literal `48.4` to the integer `48` for the call.

---

As for why it's linking, it's because while these functions *may* be implemented as macros, that's not a requirement. What *is* a requirement is that those functions, at least in the C11 standard (I don't have any older version available at the moment), have to be aware of the current locale which will make their implementation as macros much harder, and much easier as normal library functions. And as the standard library is always linked (unless you tell GCC otherwise) the functions will be available.

Answer (score 4):

First of all `#include` statements don't have anything to do with `linking`. Remember anything with a `#` in-front in `C` is meant for the preprocessor, not the compiler or the linker.

But that said the function has to be linked isn't it?

Let's do the steps in separate steps.

```
$ gcc -c -Werror --std=c99 st.c 
st.c: In function ‘main’:
st.c:5:22: error: implicit declaration of function ‘isdigit’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     printf("%d %d\n",isdigit(48),isdigit(48.4));
                      ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Well as you see gcc's lint(static analyzer) is in action!

Whatever we will proceed to ignore it...

```
$ gcc -c  --std=c99 st.c 
st.c: In function ‘main’:
st.c:5:22: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘isdigit’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("%d %d\n",isdigit(48),isdigit(48.4));
```

This time only an warning. Now we have a object file at the current directory. Let's inspect it...

```
$ nm st.o 
                 U isdigit
0000000000000000 T main
                 U printf
```

As you can see both `printf` and `isdigit` is listed as undefined. So the code has to come from somewhere isn't it?

let's proceed to link it ...

```
$ gcc st.o
$ nm a.out | grep  'printf\|isdigit'
                 U isdigit@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Well as you can see situation is mildly improved. As `isdigit` and `printf` are not helpless loners like they were in the `st.o`. You could see both of the functions are provided by `GLIBC_2.2.5`. But where is that `GLIBC`?

Well let's examine the final executable a bit more...

```
$ ldd a.out 
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe58d70000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb66f299000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055b26631d000)
```

AHA...there is that `libc` . So it turns out, though you have not given any instruction, the linker is linking with 3 libraries by default, one of them is the `libc` which contains both `printf` and `isdigit`.

You can see the default behaviour of the linker by :

```
$gcc -dumpspec
*link:
%{!r:--build-id} %{!static:--eh-frame-hdr} %{!mandroid|tno-android-ld:%{m16|m32|mx32:;:-m elf_x86_64}                    %{m16|m32:-m elf_i386}                    %{mx32:-m elf32_x86_64}   --hash-style=gnu   --as-needed   %{shared:-shared}   %{!shared:     %{!static:       %{rdynamic:-export-dynamic}       %{m16|m32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker;:/lib/ld-linux.so.2}}}       %{m16|m32|mx32:;:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld64-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker64;:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2}}}       %{mx32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ldx32-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linkerx32;:/libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2}}}}     %{static:-static}};:%{m16|m32|mx32:;:-m elf_x86_64}                    %{m16|m32:-m elf_i386}                    %{mx32:-m elf32_x86_64}   --hash-style=gnu   --as-needed   %{shared:-shared}   %{!shared:     %{!static:       %{rdynamic:-export-dynamic}       %{m16|m32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker;:/lib/ld-linux.so.2}}}       %{m16|m32|mx32:;:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ld64-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linker64;:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2}}}       %{mx32:-dynamic-linker %{muclibc:/lib/ldx32-uClibc.so.0;:%{mbionic:/system/bin/linkerx32;:/libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2}}}}     %{static:-static}} %{shared: -Bsymbolic}}
```

What are the other two libraries?

Well remember when you dug into `a.out`, both `printf` and `isdigit` were still shown  as `U` that means unknown. In other words, there were no `memory` address associated with these symbols.

In reality this is where the magic lies. These libraries were actually loaded during runtime, not during link time like older systems.

How it's implemented? Well it has a jargon associated with, something like *lazy linking*. What it does, is when the process calls a function , if there is no memory address(TEXT section), it generates a `Trap` (Something like a Exception in high level language jargon, when control is handed over to the language engine). The kernel intercepts such `Trap` and hands it over to the dynamic loader which loads the library and returns the associated memory address to the caller process.

There are multiple theoretical reason, why doing things lazily is better than doing it beforehand. I guess that's a whole new topic, which we will discuss at some other time.